# How long does it take to hear back about a Grand Canyon Backcountry permit application

Tags: backcountry, permits

We've applied for corridor campsites for May 2013 - problem was that we applied January 21st.

How long does it generally take to hear if we've got reservations?  (Our alternative is to wait and apply for late September)

Comment: Wouldn't asking them be the obvious thing to do?

Answer (score 7):

From the [GRCA back-country permit site](http://www.nps.gov/grca/planyourvisit/backcountry-permit.htm):

> Permit Responses
>
> Permit requests are responded to through U.S. Mail - never by fax or
>   e-mail. Due to the volume of requests received, the park cannot
>   confirm receipt of requests until they have been fully processed.
>   **Please allow at least three weeks for processing.**

It does suggest that for hiking in May, you apply on January 1, so you may be a little late to the game. (For Sept, they suggest applying on or after May 1.)

However, they do accept walk-in reservations, and you might get lucky and get a cancellation. See [this answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/1165/86) for additional information.